# Handlebars onclick view more not displaying the data from my json file

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

ive successfully created a helper and function that display data from a json file in a styled list using handlebars.But im struggling with the view more section of my code.Basically what im trying to achieve is,if user clicks on a list item,handlebars should get the id of that item and display it on a different page.My console correctly displays the correct id for each item clicked on the new page(viewdetail page)but the page only displays the styling but with no content from my json.This is my handlebars code:

```
function getParameterByName(name,url){ 
    'use strict';
    if(!url)url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]"+name+"(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if(!results)return null;
    if(!results[2])return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g,""));

}
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'jj.json');
ourRequest.onload = function () {
if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
    var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    createHTML(data);
  } else {
    console.log("You are connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
  }

};

ourRequest.onerror = function() {
console.log("Connection error");
};

ourRequest.send();



function createHTML(myData) {
      var rawTemplate = document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML; 
      var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
         var myContainer = document.getElementById("this-container");
         var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(myData); 
                     myContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
            var characterId = getParameterByName("id");

        console.log(characterId);



          $.ajax("jj.json").done(function(cast){

              if ($("body").hasClass("viewdetail")){

                ///i cant seem to figure out how to render it here 
              var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(myData); 
                      myContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;


              } else

                   var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(myData); 
                      myContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
                  {

                  }
                });
    }
```

And my html is as folows:(The viewdetails page)

```
    <body class="viewdetail"
    <div class="page-wrap">
  <div id="this-container"></div>
</div>
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<span class="username"><a href="#">{{cname}}</a></span>
</script>
```

Ive tried using {{#each}} and {{#each myjsonobject}}
but i keep getting the correct id on the detail page,but no data in the styling.
What am i doing wrong here,please help :(
my detail page is being hrefed from my index page as follows:

```
<a href="detailpage.php?id={{id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs view-detail"><b>View</b></a>
```

And heres a portion of my json data:

```
{"content":[{"id":"60","cname":"Admin","crep":"wew","sub_type":"memember ","token":"887618243","reference":"#5754","company_email":"rereee@gmail.com","company_phone":"234556566","service1":"erty","service2":"vbnmj","service3":"yjyt","service4":"uikjyj","company_website":"www.memeber.com","company_address":null,"company_location":"namibia","company_shortbio":"sasasa","company_longbio":"bvbvbvbvb","logos":"891319.png","logopath":"","imageA":"309129.png","imageB":"898798.jpg","imageC":"452926.jpg","imageD":"326704.jpg","company_facebook":null,"company_twitter":null,"company_linkedin":null,"company_stumbleupon":null,"company_pinterest":null,"company_googleplus":null,"user_backgroundpicture":null,"created_on":"2017-01-20 15:37:02","company_skype":null,"company_youtube":null,"company_vimeo":null,"headerimg":"993621.png","join_date":"2017-01-20 15:37:02.069147":""}
```

Comment: What does the object, `myData`, look like?

Comment: console.log(myData); displays an array of objects from my json file on the console

Comment: so i fixed that and myData object on the console displays the array of objects from my json file,and when i console log the characterId,i get the correct id for each view.But still no data ,just styling on the view details page

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you are passing the full data-set contained in your JSON into your template rather than just the single record you want to display. You simply need to find the character object in the array of characters and use that as the parameter to your template method.

```
var characterId = getParameterByName("id");    
var characters = myData.content;
var character = characters.find(function (_character) {
    return _character.id === characterId;
});
var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(character);

myContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
```

Comment: this is not working for me...try using the json file i provided

Comment: @AngelaDutchan What isn't working for you? Do you get a value for `character`?

Comment: no value for character.Console returns an  id and the array on console log mydata,but the page fails to render the content contained in the specific id

Comment: basically using {{each}}  displays my content correctly on the viewdetail page,but the problem is that,{{each}} displays everything in the array.And removing {{each}}  displays nothing.Is there a way i should be using {{each}}  on my viewdetail page?

Comment: You should not be using `{{#each}}`. Since you want to display a single record, you should get that record out of the array and pass that to your template, as my answer demonstrates.

Comment: @AngelaDutchan Perhaps you could try the following and tell us the result: `console.log(myData);`, `console.log(myData.content);`, `console.log(characterId);`, `console.log(typeof characterId);`

Comment: console.log(myData); returns  Object { content: Array[38] }   console.log(myData.content);   returns   Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 28 more… ]     console.log(characterId); returns    the id of the item           console.log(typeof characterId); returns string

Comment: The issue is not the handlebars code now,its how to use each,if,...etc in my handles bars html script.I am curretly using {{#with object. [array number]}}     i.e:{{with content.[0]}} returns the object with id zero.But now how do i get this to work properly without me having to manually put in the array object[0],in handlebars

Answer (score 0):

With these kinds of issues it is important to isolate where the problem is occurring. First, I would try to determine if the issue is in the template or in the data being passed to the template.

To detect this, I would put `console.log(myData);` just before where you pass the data to the `compiledTemplate()` call. If the data looks the way you expect, then you would consider what is happening with your template.

First, understanding how data is used by the handlebars template is important. If, for example, I pass an object like this:

`myData = { a: 4, b: 3 };`

to my template, I would expect to use constructs like {{a}} and {{b}} in my template.

If, however, I pass something like this:

`myData = { content: [{ id: 1, cname: 'Hi'}, { id: 2, cname: 'There' }] };`

then I would expect that I would have access to `content`. If I wanted to get at the data in the array, then I would need to do something like:

```
{{#each content}}
  Name: {{cname}}
{{/each}}
```

Now, suppose you just want a particular item in the array. Then you should use javascript to isolate that item and only pass that item to your template. Using the previous example, and assuming `myId` is the id you want to render through your template:

```
var item myData.content.find(function(item) {
  return (item.id === myId);
});
var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(item);
```

Now in your template, you can just use {{id}} and {{cname}}, for example, to build your html. No need for an #each since there is no array, just a single object.

If the property in your object is `lodges`, then switch out `content` for `lodges` in the above code snippet.

Comment: {{#each content}}
  Name: {{cname}}
{{/each}} returns every single item in my array.My aim is to return only one item based on each id

Comment: console.log(myData); returns Object { lodges: Array[38] }...and object array shows all the items in the array on the console

Comment: Okay, updated answer to give you an approach. If the object has property of 'lodges' (before it was 'content')... not sure why it keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

ok,so after extensive research,i discovered this:

Using {{#with}} in my html actually produced one item from the array of objects with the data and styling.Now the next step is to figure out how to implement it in the handlebars js code.But this is what i did so far and its working great:

```
{{#with content.[0]}}
```

0 being the id of the item in the array.It could be any number depending on which item you want to parse.